# Delete invalid records related self problem

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `comments` table. Structure like this

```
id  parent_id  user_id  comment  
--  ---------  -------  -------
```

I want to delete records where have incorrect related values.
For delete records where user_id is invalid value I use this query

```
DELETE FROM `comments` WHERE `user_id` NOT IN (SELECT `id` FROM `users`)
```

but when I try to delete records where parent_id is invalid data I use this query

```
DELETE FROM `comments` WHERE `parent_id` NOT IN (SELECT `id` FROM `comments`)
```

I get this error

> Error Code: 1093 You can't specify target table 'comments' for update
>   in FROM clause

Comment: This may have a duplicate but the suggested duplicate does not apply to `not in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do what you want with cascading foreign key constraints.

That said, you can accomplish this using `left join`:

```
DELETE c
    FROM comments c LEFT JOIN
         comments cp
         ON c.parent_id = cp.id
    WHERE cp.id IS NULL AND
          c.parent_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Note the condition `c.parent_id IS NOT NULL`.  That is implied by (almost) any comparison you make on the column, including `NOT IN`.